# Offline password storage

Tags: windows, password-management

One day I got really ambitious (or paranoid) and decided I could manage my own website passwords, as opposed to having Chrome to do it for me. My "solution" isn't very user friendly, and I'm back to using Chrome for the time being.

My "solution" was this:

1. Store credentials in an excel file, call it pwords.xlsx, on an external usb drive, call it E.
2. Encrypt pwords.xlsx using 4096 bit RSA. (Keys are not stored on usb.)
3. After each use of the file (decrypting to access credentials and then re-encrypting) delete pwords.xlsx by highlighting it and entering shift+delete, so that it doesn't get sent to the recycling bin on C volume.
4. After deleting pwords.xlsx, open cmd and execute `cipher /w :E`. Apparently this command overwrites unused space on E.

What happens to the copy of pwords.xlsx in memory after I close it? I assume it's just sitting there, unencrypted, until that memory location is overwritten.

Is there a way to clean it from memory?

Lastly, on Windows, is there a way to wipe ONLY pwords.xlsx, rather than wiping the entire volume with `cipher w/`?

Comment: One might ask why you are using Excel and not one of the many free offline password managers that help to manage all these aspects of the problem.

Comment: office like to make copies of working files in deep cache folders; i would grep a literal from your file and make sure it's not sitting on your hard drive before worrying about RAM.

Comment: This seems like it is tedious and error prone. Just use a password manager like Keypass and keep the database on a USB key. Use Bitlocker as an extra layer of protection if you can. Securely deletion is achievable by losing the password. (Change it to something you don’t know.)